# get index of an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm planning to get the index of an object is it possible?

for example:

```
categories = {
                '1':{code:'HW', name:'Hardware'},
                '2':{code:'SW', name:'Software'},
                '3':{code:'OS', name:'Office Supplies'},
            }
```

I want to get the index of software if I use `indexOf` it gives me an error which is `indexOf is not a function` because it's a list of objects.
Is it possible top begin with?

Here's a sample  fiddle for you guys to check: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/86966/

thanks in advance

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly, but I noticed that in the fiddle, `categories` is an array and not an object. Which is it in your actual case?

Comment: @CRice in my actual case it's an object. on my fiddle I comment out the categories that has a list of objects.. I already know that indexOf will not work because it is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the index in `v-for` like `(category, index) in categories`, see the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/86971/).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      categories: {
        '1':{code:'HW', name:'Hardware'},
        '2':{code:'SW', name:'Software'},
        '3':{code:'OS', name:'Office Supplies'},
      }      
    }
  },
  methods:{
    alertIndex(index){
      alert(index);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
 <ul>
  <li v-for="(category, index) in categories">{{category.code}} - {{category.name}}
  <button @click="alertIndex(index)">Alert Index</button>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```